Command not found when command stored in variable
I'm trying to run an npm script from inside a bash script.  It works when I enter the command directly like this:
echo "$(npm run jest)"

But when I store the command in a variable like this, it says test-build.sh: line 115: npm run jest: command not found:
str="npm run jest"
echo "$($str)"          # this way fails
echo "$(${str})"        # this other way fails, too

What am I doing wrong? TIA.

See BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!

(You don't have a complex case -- just $str will work with no quotes if your shell is really bash and not zsh, and IFS is at its default value -- but it would be very bad practice to depend on that remaining true indefinitely; do what the FAQ advises and use a function or array instead).

(separately, it's very rare that there's a good reason to run echo "$(foo)" -- in which the output of foo is written to a FIFO, read by the shell and then passed to echo to write it to the shell's stdout -- instead of just foo, where the output of foo is written to the copy of stdout that the foo executable inherits from the shell directly, with no relaying through the shell parent process required)

thanks @CharlesDuffy, the problem was related to the IFS. To simplify, I have an array of repos I am looping over. For each, i have a comma-separated list of commands I want to run (had to change IFS for the comma). Restoring the IFS before running the command worked.

Really, don't do that. Follow the FAQ's instructions -- $str is unreliable for more reasons than just this. (It doesn't honor quoting, can silently remove arguments if they look like globs and nullglob is set, can create spurious failures if failglob is set, and is otherwise something with unintuitive, surprising behavior).

cmd=( npm run jest ) and then "${cmd[@]}" -- or cmd() { npm run jest; }; and then cmd -- isn't many more characters, but either has far fewer hidden surprises.

@markp-fuso, ...there aren't any double quotes inside the command substitution (which as you know creates a new quoting context), so IFS is genuinely being used for splitting -- but as the OP describes in a prior comment, they had set IFS=, set earlier in their script.

@AlanP., btw, if you use IFS=, read all on the same command (as compared to IFS=,; read making the assignment and the read two separate commands), the assignment will be scoped to the read command and not apply to anything subsequent. (Obviously, there are still valid reasons to sometimes need to use IFS=, on its own; but if you were just setting it for read's benefit, one can scope it to that single operation and not need to explicitly reset later).

I believe if you trying to execute command from variable in such way, shell will not perform expansions (for example npm will not be expanded to /path/to/binary/npm and so on.
So thebest way is to use eval command eval $str

@Saboteur, always quote -- eval "$str" -- otherwise you have your string word-split and glob-expanded into separate arguments, which are then concatenated together into one string that gets run through the parser again from the beginning (a chain of events that makes it easy for malicious content to slip from filenames into code if there are glob expansions involved).

@Saboteur, ...but even then, eval is bad practice (as real-use cases generally involve parameterized data rather than constant strings), so guiding people to the BashFAQ #50 solutions is very deliberate. If folks want to run expansions at evaluation time, a function lets them do that more safely.

@Saboteur, ...as an aside, having seen each other around for a while -- the orthodoxy I follow hails from the #bash IRC channel, where I was a regular denizen for a few decades in the past. Many of the norms there can be found in pithy form in the greybot factoid database, or in expanded form in the contents of the Wooledge wiki (hosting the BashFAQ, BashGuide, BashPitfalls, etc) -- they formed communally over an extended period of seeing where folks new to the language tended to make mistakes even given the preexisting references on the web.
